# Python script output specific data XML

Tags: python, xml

I have a large XML file which I'm going to use as a master Database. I need to be able to enter a specific header which a python script asks me for which will go through the XML file and only output into a new XML file the data associated with that header. I literally am stumped at where to even begin, so if anyone has any reading material to start me off that would be much appreciated

Comment: Your answer is pretty vague; can you at least give some examples of what you want to do? Also, you should read up on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
import xml.dom.minidom
key = raw_input('header ?') # input
bdFile = xml.dom.minidom.parse("/tmp/toto.xml") # parse xml
node = bdFile.getElementsByTagName(key)[0] # search
# write
resultFile = open("/tmp/destination.xml", 'w') 
resultFile.write(node.toxml())
resultFile.close()
```